# Cache manifest in HTML5 does not work in google chrome but perfectly working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, html, cache-manifest

Hope everyone is fine. 
I am facing a new problem of Cache Manifest. I am using it with my php application. It works fine in mozilla but not works perfectly in mozilla firefox. Here is my code. Please suggest me how can i overcome this problem.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v1
CACHE:
css/w3.css
css/icon/css/font-awesome.min.css
css/style.css
css/responsive.css
css/select2.min.css
css/bootstrap.min.css
css/perfect-scrollbar.css
js/perfect-scrollbar.js
js/jquery.min.js
js/bootstrap.min.js
js/select2.min.js   
NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: AppCache has been deprecated for years.

Comment: what the alternative way regarding this problem??